# Erro 403 - o servidor web está configurado para não listar o conteudo

Tags: c#, iis

Estou com problemas para executar meu servidor local no Visual Studio 2013. Quando tento executar minha aplicação aparece a seguinte tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se precisarem de mais algo, avisem que edito e coloco aqui o que for necessário.

Comment: O que acontece se você acessar `http://localhost:56377/CadastroMidia`?

Answer (score -1):

Pode ser:

1. Problemas de permissões na pasta do projeto
2. Problemas de permissões na configuração do projeto no IIS.
3. Arquivo padrão para listagem do projeto.

Se nada disso resolver, dê mais detalhes do problema para que possamos ajudar.